# Login Error when using a Google Account

Tags: bug, login, google-openid

When I try to use a Google account to authenticate to a StackExchange account, something strange happens -- On clicking the "Log in with Google" button with Google *unauthenticated*, the sign in to google completes fine but instead of getting redirected to the page before login, this appears on the screen and I can't login. Refreshing the page doesn't change it either.

[image: Login fail]

The message reads:

> Request lacked state, may have been forged

But with Google already authenticated before clicking the `Log In` button, login to SE works as expected.

Comment: On a now [deleted question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402727) a comment from the OP said: *Turns out the anti tracker provided by my antivirus was causing the error.*

Comment: Yes turns out my adblocker is causing this. Thanks @rene

Comment: Would you mind writing a self-answer describing which ad blocker you used and how or what you disabled?

Comment: Sure, I'll try to rule out if a particular feature of the adblock was causing this and describe it in an answer

Comment: So I happened to be certain that the ad blocker was the cause when I gave the comment because disabling it solved the issue. I guessed this could be it because it has an anti-tracker - a possible cause mentioned in rene's comment (first). This was on Chromium browser (v84.0.4147.105), the ad blocker being Ad Block Plus. However, I can't reproduce this fix on a different browser (Firefox v80.0 for Ubuntu). I have tried disabling all content-filters and ad blockers, including all browser extensions but in this case, the error persists.

Answer (score 3):

Removing the [BitDefender Anti-Tracker Chrome Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bitdefender-anti-tracker/khndhdhbebhaddchcgnalcjlaekbbeof) fixed the problem for me.