# Manjaro/Firefox: Can't log in to Stack Overflow via Google account - "Request lacked state, may have been forged"

Tags: support, login, linux

I **cleared all my browsing data**, **disabled and uninstalled all Firefox addons** (extensions), and restarted my laptop.

I still get this:

[image: "Request lacked state, may have been forged"]

I also tried **Private Mode** (incognito) and that didn't help either. Finally, I **uninstalled Firefox** via `sudo pacman -Rns firefox` and reinstalled it, but the same problem again!

Here's what is added in the cookies exceptions on Firefox:

[image: stackoverflow.com with and without 'www' and with 'http' and 'https'.]

I'm very confused, and I'm not sure what else to do.

To ensure that my clock was right, I ran `timedatectl set-ntp true` on Manjaro and can see that the clock is correct.

I now get:

[image: "There was an error fetching your account from Google. Please try logging in again."]

I have already seen [this similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356729/stack-overflow-login-problem-i-cant-log-in), but it didn't help.

Comment: You did add the exception in firefox as mentioned in the question you linked or did you correctly added 'stackoverflow.com' (without the www. part) in the exception list?

Comment: @rene I have, see the screenshot. Still get the same error.

Comment: @mindstormsboi that's the question I linked to myself. All the suggestions in there didn't help.

Comment: Some anti virus or security software on your machine might also mess with cookies and force the browsers to not store them. What anti virus and/or security software you have installed?

Comment: Okay, add `https://stackauth.com` as well in that exception list

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard I do not have any security software installed (no anti-virus or anything else). @rene, I also added `https://stackauth.com` to the whitelist, along with `stackexchange.com`, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Might sound silly, but please check your computer clock, make sure it's correct. Even if correct, synchronize it with some global time server.

Comment: Related (covers cookies, etc.): *[Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)*

Comment: @rene might this be related to your Q on SEDE log in?

Comment: @Luuklag Maybe but I would need to see the network calls then to confirm. This also seems later in the process. The connection is made here and SE code refuses to authenticate. In my SEDE bug the browser is rejecting the connection. That is clearly not happening here.

Comment: Something tells me that this is a CSRF issue, meaning that your browser is interfering with the way the HTTP request is made.

Comment: hmm, but I uninstalled, then re-installed, and have all add-ons disabled in Firefox.

Comment: Google also had major issues over the last 2 hours so .... Can you maybe switch network? As in go over a different ISP? maybe use a VPN?

Comment: I get the same, firefox 90.0.1 (64-bit) on Manjaro, but works fine in chrome

Answer (score -2):

Try to log out of Google search, just in case you have searched Google or logged in any other services using your Google account credentials. Then try again to login in to Stack Overflow.