# Logging in via Chrome on Android: Request lacked state, may have been forged

Tags: support, login, cookies, google-openid, mobile-chrome

I get this semi-regularly when I try to log into sites on the stackexchange network, today it's for superuser.com.

I follow the pattern of <kbd>Log in</kbd>→<kbd>Log in with Google</kbd> and I get the familiar error message:

> Request lacked state, may have been forged

Which is just charming, it's too early to be accused of being stateless and forged...

It makes no difference whether I navigate to superuser via Google, directly from entering the url, nor via a link to the site in my stackoverflow profile.

I'm on Chrome 95.something, I have do not track enabled, and my cookie settings are "Block third-party cookies in Incognito" (for what it's worth, I'm not using incognito mode).

If I run this bookmark let, to pretty print my cookies...:

```js
javascript:document.write(`<pre>${JSON.stringify(document.cookie.split(';').reduce((cookies, val) => { [cookieName, parts] = val.split(/=(.+)/); cookies[cookieName] = parts.split('&'); return cookies; }, {}), null, 2)}</pre>`)
```

I get the following JSON out:

```json
{
  "_ga": [
    "GA1.2.1999678813.1635498073"
  ],
  " _gid": [
    "GA1.2.215224952.1635498073"
  ],
  " OptanonAlertBoxClosed": [
    "2021-10-29T09:07:28.397Z"
  ],
  " OptanonConsent": [
    "isIABGlobal=false",
    "datestamp=Fri+Oct+29+2021+10%3A07%3A28+GMT%2B0100+(British+Summer+Time)",
    "version=6.10.0",
    "hosts=",
    "landingPath=NotLandingPage",
    "groups=C0003%3A0%2CC0004%3A0%2CC0002%3A0%2CC0001%3A1"
  ]
}
```

So I am not sure where to go from here?

- [Stack Overflow login problem - I can't log in!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356729/175002) is about desktop browsers, but even then I don't have adblock, and as mentioned I already have "Block third-party cookies in Incognito" set.
- [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/175002) accepted answer links to [Stackexchange's Browserlist](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design) which currently lists Chrome 95 supported as a desktop browser, and only Chrome 94 supported as a mobile browser, however that linked answer says:

> If you don’t see your browser listed, it may still work, but with a degraded experience.

So I'm not *wholly* convinced it's the browser version, whoever I could be convinced if there was some explanation? It seems to *only* be logging in, as I can browse stacks where I am already logged in with no issues.

- [Login Error when using a Google Account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356383/175002) also looks irrelevant, as that relates to a desktop issue

What if anything can I do besides downgrading chrome and/or waiting for StackExchange to support logging in on Chrome 95?